# How can I assign the ROWID through a variable in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

Is there a way I can assign an SQLite rowid through a variable in Python? I am using Tkinters *'get()'* function to retrieve the contents of the entry.

Here is the code:

```
def insertdata():
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Students VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", (surnamelabelentry.get(), forenamelabelentry.get(), dateofbirthlabelentry.get(), homeaddresslabelentry.get(), homephonenumberentry.get(), genderlabelentry.get(), tutorgrouplabelentry.get(), emaillabelentry.get()))
    c.execute('INSERT INTO Students(rowid) VALUES',(studentidentry.get()))
    conn.commit()
    rootE.destroy()
```

Here is the error:

*File "R:/Documents/PYTHON/Login And Pw.py", line 124, in insertdata
    c.execute('INSERT INTO Students(rowid) VALUES',(studentidentry.get()))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "VALUES": syntax error*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing the `(?)` on the second `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating your table, declare one column as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
    StudentID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Surname VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    Forename VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

This makes that column an alias for the `ROWID`, and you can then use a normal `INSERT` statement to set it.

If for some bizarre reason you want to keep ROWID as a hidden column but still set an explicit value for it, then you can use an explicit column list for `INSERT`.

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO Students(ROWID, Surname, Forename) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (5678, 'Tables', 'Robert'))
```